# Compiling Problems using freeglut

Tags: c++, git, makefile, codeblocks, freeglut

**PREFACE**

So I've been recently programming c++ in Code::Blocks and have run into a problem compiling recently when trying to compile projects that include freeglut. I'm on windows 8, and I have installed freeglut correctly according to the [code::blocks wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Using_FreeGlut_with_Code::Blocks). I also have git bash installed as well as mingw64. The problem is that I cannot compile the source code that my professor (project using freeglut)  has written using code::blocks or using g++ commands in gitbash.

**main.cpp:**

```
/* Copyright (c) Mark J. Kilgard, 1996. */

/* This program is freely distributable without licensing fees
and is provided without guarantee or warrantee expressed or
implied. This program is -not- in the public domain. */

#include "Graphics.h"
void display(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  setColor(RED);
  drawFilledTriangle(0,0,100,100,200,0);
  setColor(BLUE);
  drawFilledCircle(200,200,150);
  glFlush();  /* Single buffered, so needs a flush. */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  graphicsSetup( argc, argv, &display);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

**Graphics.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Graphics.h"
#include <cmath>
const double PI = acos(-1.0);
const double ANGLE_STEP      = PI/180.0;
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 27)
        exit(1);
}

void clearWindow() {
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
}

void setColor(ColorName name) {
    switch(name) {
        case WHITE: glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); break;
        case GREY: glColor3d(0.4, 0.4, 0.4); break;
        case BLACK: glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); break;
        case RED: glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); break;
        case ORANGE: glColor3d(1.0, 0.5, 0.0); break;
        case YELLOW: glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0); break;
        case GREEN: glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); break;
        case FOREST_GREEN: glColor3d(0.0, 0.25, 0.0); break;
        case BLUE: glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); break;
        case CYAN: glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 1.0); break;
        case MIDNIGHT_BLUE: glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.25); break;
        case PURPLE: glColor3d(0.5, 0.25, 0.0); break;
        case MAGENTA: glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 1.0); break;
        case BROWN: glColor3d(0.36, 0.16, 0.1); break;
        default: cerr << "Trying to set invalid color. Color unchanged" << endl;
    }
}
void graphicsSetup(int argc, char *argv[], void (*display)()) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
  if (! glutGet(GLUT_DISPLAY_MODE_POSSIBLE))
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_INDEX);
  glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
  glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
  glutCreateWindow("single triangle");
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);

  // set "esc" key to end program
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

  // set coordinates to "normal"
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0,640,0,480, 1, -1);
}

void drawTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y2);
     glVertex2i(x3,y3);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glEnd();
}

void drawFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y2);
     glVertex2i(x3,y3);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glEnd();
}

void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y2);
     glEnd();
}

void drawBox(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y2);
     glVertex2i(x1,y2);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glEnd();
}

void drawFilledBox(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y1);
     glVertex2i(x2,y2);
     glVertex2i(x1,y2);
     glVertex2i(x1,y1);
     glEnd();
}

void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
     double angle;
     int X, Y;
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
     for (angle=0;angle< 2.0*PI + ANGLE_STEP; angle += ANGLE_STEP) {
         X = x + int(double(radius) * cos(angle));
         Y = y + int(double(radius) * sin(angle));
         glVertex2i(X,Y);
     }
     glEnd();
}         

void drawFilledCircle(int x, int y, int radius) {
     double angle;
     int X0, Y0, X1, Y1;
     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
     X1 = x + radius;
     Y1 = y;
         for (angle=0;angle< 2.0*PI + ANGLE_STEP; angle += ANGLE_STEP) {
             X0 = X1;
             Y0 = Y1;
             X1 = x + int(double(radius) * cos(angle));
             Y1 = y + int(double(radius) * sin(angle));
             glVertex2i(x,y);
             glVertex2i(X0,Y0);
             glVertex2i(X1,Y1);
         }
         glEnd();
    }
```

**Graphics.h**

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

// set the pre-defined colors
enum ColorName {
    WHITE,
    GREY,
    BLACK,
    RED,
    ORANGE,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    FOREST_GREEN,
    BLUE,
    MIDNIGHT_BLUE,
    CYAN,
    PURPLE,
    MAGENTA,
    BROWN,
    NUM_COLORS
};

void clearWindow();
void setColor(ColorName name);
void graphicsSetup(int argc, char *argv[], void (*display)());

// graphic object primatives
void drawTriangle(int x1, int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3);
void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
void drawBox(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2); // x-y coords of upper-right     and lower-left corners
void drawCircle(int x, int y, int radius);

// filled graphics primatives
void drawFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3);
void drawFilledBox(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
void drawFilledCircle(int x, int y, int radius);
```

**makefile**

```
TARGET = test.exe

CXX   = c:\usr\local\mingw32\bin\g++.exe
FILES = main.cpp Graphics.cpp
OBJS = $(FILES:.cpp=.o)

GINCS   = -I/usr/local/include/GL 
GLIBS   = -L/usr/local/lib -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows

all:  $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(GLIBS)

%.o:    %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(GINCS)

clean:
    del $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

**COMPILING IN GIT**

1. I `cd`into the directory containing `main.cpp ; Graphics.cpp ; Graphics.h ; makefile`.
2. I then run `make`and get the following even though I have added all the freeglut lib, include, and bin content files into the correct directories under C:\usr\local\mingw32(inlcude\,lib\,bin) and GL\glut.h is definently there...

> ```
> $ make
> c:\usr\local\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -c main.cpp -o main.o -I/usr/local/include/GL
> In file included from main.cpp:7:0:
> Graphics.h:1:21: fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> makefile:16: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
> make: *** [main.o] Error 1
> ```

**COMPILING IN CODE::BLOCKS**

3. I open `main.cpp ; Graphics.h ; Graphics.cpp` in code::blocks.
4. With main.cpp active, I "build and run". **I get this error and nothing seems to happen, except that now there is a main.o in the project directory.**

> ```
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `glClear@4'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `setColor(ColorName)'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `drawFilledTriangle(int, int, int, int, int, int)'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `setColor(ColorName)'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `drawFilledCircle(int, int, int)'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `glFlush@0'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `graphicsSetup(int, char**, void (*)())'
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\cosc1337.code\GraphicsLib\examples\ex4\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp__glutMainLoop@0'
> === Build failed: 11 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
> ```

5. Same thing as above when Graphics.cpp is active and I `build and run`, I get the same errors as before, but Graphics.o is created.

**WRAPPING THIS UP:**

*After I have created the object files using code::blocks, I am able to then get on gitbash and run the makefile to link them, and it does create a working test.exe that I can run and see where my placement is, but I am perplexed and frustrated that I cannot use just code::blocks or just git, as doing this makes adjustments to the code take an unreasonable amount of time to get satisfactory and is sure to cause problems later on*

**EDIT**

All other [Programs](https://github.com/pedersenzach/Homework.git) I have written, as well as 'hello world' compile with no problem on code::blocks and gitbash.

Comment: This sounds like your makefile, or your code::blocks, or both are misconfigured. I would recommend just trying to compile extremely simple programs like `int main() {}` until you can do it reliably and consistently without errors in both ways. As long as you cannot do that your system needs some work. Then gradually try including free glut and such until you can get it to work, and post again on SO if you really get stuck somewhere.

Comment: All other programs I have written will compile with no problem in code::blocks and git bash. And I always make sure the hello world will compile from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Building in Console

Building project using `Makefile` consists of two steps:

- compilation of source files to binary object files
- linkage of object files to excecutable

It can be done using just MinGW from pure `cmd` console. The only requirement is to set the `PATH` variable to point to MinGW binaries. It can be done locally only for that console, for example:

```
PATH=c:\MinGW\mingw-w64\i686-5.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev0\mingw32\bin;%PATH%
```

Suppose that the binary [freeglut 3.0.0 MinGW Package](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) is extracted to folder `c:\freeglut`.

```
::compilation
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o -I"c:\freeglut\include"
g++ -c Graphics.cpp -o Graphics.o -I"c:\freeglut\include"

::linkage
g++ Graphics.o main.o -o test -L"c:\freeglut\lib" -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

During compilation `main.o` and `Graphics.o` object files are generated.

In your case the error is on this step. It is related to the header path. Check that in your `gitbash` the path `/usr/local/include/` indeed exists by listing it `ls /usr/local/include/`. If it exists then note that in your source files the header is included as `GL/glut.h` and also `GL` directory is present in `GINCS`. It is an error if the header path is `/usr/local/include/GL/glut.h`. So, remove `GL` from `GINCS`.

The linkage step produces the target `test.exe` binary.

### Code::Blocks project

The Code::Blocks IDE can be tuned to make GLUT project template to work with `freeglue` as described in [Using FreeGlut with Code::Blocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Using_FreeGlut_with_Code::Blocks).

It is just needed to replace `Glut32` by `freeglut` in the wizard script `glut\wizard.script` and in the project template `glut.cbp`.

Now it is possible to create a new project using `GLUT project` preset. It will only ask you `glut` path. Then Code::Blocks automatically creates project configured with required compiler options (header path) and linker options (path and libraries). It also gives the `main.cpp` file with basic example that can be compiled as is.

It looks that you created not a `GLUT project` but just a regular empty application project. To make it work you need to configure `Project build options`:

- `Search directories`: add path in the `Compiler` tab (`c:\freeglut\include`) and in the `Linker` tab (`c:\freeglut\lib`);
- `Linker settings`: add names of required libraries without `l` prefix (`freeglut`, `glu32`, `opengl32`).

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. But it also turns out that the problem was that I wasnt building my files in the glut project template.

Answer (score 0):

In your make files I see you are linking with flags like `-lfreeglut`. I use linux and I remember having to put all the l's in front of my link options for linux specifically. Try using `-freeglut` and ect. for the others.

In code::blocks you can add the glut32.lib by going to `Project>Build` Options and then go to the `linker` tab. There click `add` under `link libraries`. Then give it the path to you .lib files. Be sure not to use a relative path. You want the literal path.

My only other suggestion is to `#include <windows.h>`. Usually when you get a slew of undefined references like that, it is some kind of linking error.

Comment: I will edit the makefile right now and try to compile. Im hoping this is it, since these sourcefiles are straight from my professor and I did have to change some of the makefile, but nothing big at all.

On your code::blocks suggestion, the code::blocks wiki directions had me go through the wizard.script for glut and change all references to glut32 to freeglut. Im not sure this will work, but Im willing to try anything right now.
 

Thank you, will get back after

Comment: Changed my makefile and took out the `l` in front of the references, same error still. Upon inspection (code::blocks' mingw and my mingw64 lib paths) I dont see any glut32.lib or glut32.a, but the freeglut.a files are in both.